# C callbacks and non-Go threads

Tags: c, gcc, callback, go

1. How does one call Go code in C from threads that weren't created by Go?
2. What do I assign to a C function pointer such that threads not created by Go can call that pointer and enter into Go code?

### Update0

- I don't want to use SWIG.
- The callbacks will be coming from threads Go hasn't seen before. Neither `cgo/life` nor anything in `pkg/runtime` demonstrates this behaviour AFAICT.

Comment: Oh wait, you're ON the go-nuts list and you are the one who just asked that question some hours ago.

Comment: @Matt Kane: Doing what I can to increase visibility and documentation of golang, which is at rock bottom.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an idea, but I still don't believe this can be done.

Comment: Well, I wrote my answer before your update when SWIG wasn't proscribed. In fact, your update adds a whole lot more detail that wasn't present at the time. No sense taking the bounty.

Comment: Any takers for this bounty? There are only 2 Go users in all of SO?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll assume you mean from C code compiled with gcc?

IIRC, this either can't be done or can't easily be done using 6g+cgo and friends. Go uses a different calling convention (as well as the segmented stacks and such).

However, you *can* write C code for [685]c (or even [685]a) and call into go easily using package·function() (you can even call methods IIRC). See the [Source of the `runtime` package](http://golang.org/src/pkg/runtime) for examples.

### Update:

Coming back to this question after the update, and giving it some more thought. This can't be done in a standard fashion using 6c or cgo. Especially because the threads are not started by the go runtime, the current implementation would fail. The scheduler would suddenly have a thread under its control that it does not know about; additionally, that thread would be missing some thread-local variables the go runtime uses for managing stacks and some other things. Also, if the go function returns a value (or several) the C code can't access it on the currently supported platforms, as go returns values on the stack (you could access them with assembly though). With these things in mind, I do believe you could still do this using channels. It would require your C code to be a little too intimate with the inner workings of the go runtime, but it would work for a given implementation. While using channels may not be the solution you're looking for, it could possibly fit more nicely with the concepts of Go than callbacks. If your C code reimplemented at least the sending methods in [The channel implementation](http://golang.org/src/pkg/runtime/chan.c) (that code is written for 6c, so it would have to be adapted for gcc most likely, and it calls the go runtime, which we've determined can't be done from a non-go thread), you should be able to lock the channel and push a value to it. The go scheduler can continue to manage it's own threads, but now it can receive data from other threads started in C.

Admittedly, it's a hack; I haven't looked close enough, but it would probably take a few other hacks to get it working (I believe the channels themselves maintain a list of the goroutines that are waiting on them [EDIT: confirmed: `runtime·ready(gp);`], so you'd need something in your go code to wake up the receiving channel or to warranty the go code won't receive on the channel until you've already pushed a value). However, I can't see any reason this *can't* work, whereas there are definite reasons that running code generated by 6g on a thread created in C can't.

My original answer still holds though: **barring an addition to the language or runtime, this can't yet be done** the way you'd like (I'd love to be proven wrong here).

Comment: I would also love you to be proven wrong, the current situation is most unfortunate.

Comment: @Matt Joiner but it appears Russ gave the same answer, no new threads with the current runtime.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this, but the solution is relatively slow (about 22µs per call on my machine).
The answer is for the C code to use C thread primitives to communicate with another goroutine that will actually run the callback.

I have created a Go package that provides this functionality: [rog-go.googlecode.com/hg/exp/callback](http://code.google.com/p/rog-go/source/browse/exp/callback/).
There is an example package demonstrating its use [here](http://code.google.com/p/rog-go/source/browse/exp/example/looper/looper.go). The example demonstrates a call back to an arbitrary Go closure from a thread created outside of the Go runtime. Another example is [here](http://code.google.com/p/rog-go/source/browse/exp/example/event). This demonstrates a typical C callback interface and layers a Go callback on top of it.

To try out the first example:

```
goinstall rog-go.googlecode.com/hg/exp/example/looper
cd $GOROOT/src/pkg/rog-go.googlecode.com/hg/exp/example/looper
gotest
```

To try out the second example:

```
goinstall rog-go.googlecode.com/hg/exp/example/event
cd $GOROOT/src/pkg/rog-go.googlecode.com/hg/exp/example/event
gotest
```

Both examples assume that pthreads are available. Of course, this is just a stop-gap measure until cgo is fixed, but the technique for calling arbitrary Go closures in a C callback will be applicable even then.

Here is the documentation for the callback package:

**PACKAGE**

```
package callback
import "rog-go.googlecode.com/hg/exp/callback"
```

**VARIABLES**

```
var Func = callbackFunc
```

Func holds a pointer to the C callback function.
When called, it calls the provided function f in a
a Go context with the given argument.

It can be used by first converting it to a function pointer
and then calling from C.
Here is an example that sets up the callback function:

```
//static void (*callback)(void (*f)(void*), void *arg);
//void setCallback(void *c){
//  callback = c;
//}
import "C"
import "rog-go.googlecode.com/hg/exp/callback"

func init() {
    C.setCallback(callback.Func)
}
```

Comment: Ah, I thought of trying to use Go synchronization from C but never the other way around.

Comment: I took a look but couldn't work out what was going on at a glance.

Comment: in the looper example or the callback package?

Comment: both. Could you provide an example c struct put a go callback on it then call from c?

Comment: @Matt: done, and answer updated. please let me know how you get on with this example.

Answer (score 3):

You can find a real-world application of rog's callback package in these bindings for the PortAudio audio I/O library:  http://code.google.com/p/portaudio-go/.  Might make it easier to understand..

(Thanks for implementing that, rog.  It's just what I needed!)

Comment: It doesn't appear that the current version of this code use's rog's package at all.  Did something change in cgo itself that permits this, now?

Comment: @BadZen Something changed in cgo a _long_ time ago.